# Can't Import Desirable Number of Tweets GetOldTweets3

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I am experimenting with the `GetOldTweet3` library and I fail to achieve my goal.

I am using the following CLI command:

```
GetOldTweets3 --querysearch "Elon" --since 2019-01-01 --until 2020-06-05 --maxtweets 1000000 --toptweets
```

In simple terms, I am trying to **scrape** daily tweets related to keyword `"Elon"`

from: January 1st, 2019

To the current day.

When running this command, instead of getting the top daily tweets since that day, I get around one thousand tweets from the last two weeks.

Does anyone know how I can import the tweets in the time-span of choice and be able to set the number of tweets I want to import per day? (if there is some better library you are aware of, do not hesitate to recommend it to me)

Best Regards,

Foxtrot Delta

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Twint https://github.com/twintproject/twint/wiki . However, there are discussions that Twint might be put out of business June 1, because Twitter changes its  web frontend. Not sure whether the same argument also applies to GetOldTweets3